# Inspect popup for chrome extension immediately closes

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to debug a chrome extension, but the [debugging tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) doesn't work for me. When I click `inspect popup` the debug window opens, and instantly closes itself.

I've also tried opening the window for the extension, right clicking it, and selecting "inspect element," but with the same result.

Here is the HTML file. I removed the javascript file, just to make sure that couldn't be causing the issue.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width: 357px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }

      img {
        margin: 5px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
      }
    </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="kitty-pic" src="http://www.tehcute.com/pics/201109/kitten-bouquet-big.jpg" />
    <img id="puppy-pic" src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5347/7147821499_52ba051aaa_z.jpg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to close and reopen chrome for extension development mode to actually be activated.

Comment: Interesting. This sounds like a bug.